# Where can I get good X11 terminal fonts?

Tags: linux, x11, font

I've always had a hard time finding fonts that look good in, say, an xterm. The standard "fixed" font (i.e., the one you get by running "xterm -font fixed") is excellent, as is "10x20".

Now I'm looking for a bigger version of either of these -- I think one that was simply a double-sized 10x20 would be perfect. Does anyone know of one, or at least know of a repository of X11 fonts that has an interface that doesn't suck?

Answer (score 1):

I like the terminus font, myself; looks good, almost all glyphs are clearly distinguishable at both small and large resolutions, bolding looks good, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I think dafont.com is a good place to find fonts.  It is not a repository but you can find a wide range of fonts that are high quality and generally scalable.

Answer (score 0):

xterm -geometry 80x26+0+0 -fn -*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-*-*-*-180-*-*-*-*-*-* -fg green -bg black

Answer (score 0):

Look for the 'inconsolata' font. In my opinion it's the most beautiful monospace font there is.
It's really the only one you need.

The repository you need is usually the package manager of your distro. Browse around, you'll find fonts.