# How do I install a font in Linux so that it's usable by xterm?

Tags: linux, x11, font

I came across [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/54639/where-can-i-get-good-x11-terminal-fonts) today asking for good Linux xterm fonts, and an answer suggests one called Terminus. I've been looking for a new terminal font for a while now, so I [downloaded it](http://www.is-vn.bg/hamster/terminus-font-4.28.tar.gz) (BTW, I'm running Ubuntu Intrepid) and read the README:

```
1.1. Quick installation.
The commands:
  $ ./configure [--prefix=PREFIX]
  $ make
  # make install
compile and install the Linux console and X11 Window System fonts, and
  # make fontdir
updates fonts.dir for X11 (if you don't know what fonts.dir is, execute the
command).

1.2. Legend.    
The file names are structured as follows: ter-u<SIZE><STYLE>.bdf    
where <SIZE> is 12, 14, 16, 20, 24, 28 or 32, and <STYLE> is n for normal
(all sizes), b for bold (all sizes except 6x12) and v for EGA/VGA bold (8x14
and 8x16 only, makes use of the eight character matrix column).
```

So I ran:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo make fontdir
```

...and I restarted X11 just to be sure, and the new font was nowhere to be found:

```
$ xterm -font ter-u14n
xterm:  unable to open font "ter-u14n", trying "fixed"....
```

Sigh. Back to the README. Later in this file, I saw:

```
4. X11 Window System.
4.1. Installation.

$ ./configure [--prefix=PREFIX | --x11dir=DIRECTORY]
$ make pcf
# make install-pcf
```

Well, I know that "xterm -font 8x16" works, so I ran "locate 8x16" and saw that this font seemed to live in /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc, so that seemed like a good --x11dir to use. So I ran:

```
$ ./configure --x11dir=/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc
$ make pcf
$ make install-pcf
$ sudo make fontdir
```

...and I restarted X11 again, and even my whole computer just for good measure, and I even verified that there were now a bunch of files like /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ter-u14n.pcf.gz on my system, but still:

```
$ xterm -font ter-u14n
xterm:  unable to open font "ter-u14n", trying "fixed"....
```

What is the magical incantation I have to perform in order to get this font working with xterm?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu has a package:

```
apt-get install xfonts-terminus xfonts-terminus-oblique
```

Note that this is in the `universe` repository, so you may have to add that to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 2):

After installing xfonts-terminus in Debian Wheezy I needed to do:

```
$ xset fp rehash
```

also, my `~/.Xresources` says:

```
xterm*utf8: 1
xterm*font: -xos4-terminus-medium-r-normal--20-200-72-72-c-100-iso10646-1
```

, where `-xos4-terminus-medium-r-normal--20-200-72-72-c-100-iso10646-1` is taken from the `fonts.dir` file where the font is installed. In my case it's `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/fonts.dir`.

You use `xterm*utf8: 1` and choose `iso10646-1` if you want utf-8. You might also need to call the wrapper script `uxterm` instead of `xterm` for utf-8 to work properly in your terminal.

All changes in `~/.Xresources` require you to do:

```
$ xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

to make them register in the current X session.

The `xterm*font` rule may be also written with wildcard asterisks like that:

```
xterm*font: -xos4-terminus-medium-r-*--20-*-*-*-*-*-iso10646-*
```

I hope this will be helpful to anybody who stumbles upon a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are the fonts listed in the encodings.dir, fonts.alias, and fonts.dir files under /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc?

Its been quite a while since I needed to add fonts on a linux host but there are helper utils, named mkfontdir, update-fonts-alias, update-fonts-dir, and update-fonts-scale, that should be installed by default.  They handle updating the metainfo that tells the X server about fonts installed on the system.  See the man pages for them.

On Debian based systems (Ubuntu has a Debian heritage), when a font .deb package is added a helper normally calls mkfontdirs automatically.  Installing the font using make may not have set things up the way your system expects.